# DecisionTree split quality using chi-squared statistic

Tags: machine-learning, python, r, decision-trees

In most of the popular packages (rpart etc.), the decision tree split is based on information gain, entropy or Gini index.

Is there a popular decision tree package ( either 'R' or python) where the node split quality can be specified using chi-squared statistic?

Answer (score 2):

Base on another [post about significance test for stopping decision tree](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/130697/chi-squared-significance-test-for-stopping-criteria-in-decision-tree) in stats stackexchange website. CHAID, QUEST, GUIDE are three options. The [QUEST](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:ql5q26bay9wJ:www.stat.wisc.edu/~loh/quest.html%20&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) was provide in binary format, but not available now.

The usage for an implementation of CHAID in R is expained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17310097/chaid-analysis-options-for-os-x-python-r). 
To install it on R

```
install.packages("partykit")
install.packages("CHAID", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
```